# Flask, How to get all variables passed into a template Jinja

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I want to retrieve all the variable names without knowing their names.

well,
I have two routes who used same template.

*app.py

```
@app.route("/toto")
def toto():
   toto = [1,2,3]
   tata = [1,2,3]
   titi = [1,2,3]
   return render_template("exemple.html", toto=toto, tata=tata, titi=titi)

@app.route("/tata")
def toto():
   tutu= [1,2,3]
   tyty = [1,2,3]
   titi = [1,2,3]
   return render_template("exemple.html", toto=toto, tyty=tyty , titi=titi)
```

*exemple.html

```
{% set var = ALL_VARIABLE %}
{% for v in var %}
    {{ v }}
{{ endfor }}
```

I repost this answer because admin think is a better idea.

Comment: This could be achieved with the package `Flask-DebugToolbar`.  However I'm also curious on how to implment this without that requirement, so have [asked another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63073545/how-to-view-all-variables-passed-to-render-template-as-done-in-flask-debugtoo) which contains some references to how this could be implemented.  (I am struggling to put it all together).  IF you need a quick fix, the debug toolbar may suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you.  Please delete the old question/post.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the 3 variables to a list like this

```
tutu= [1,2,3]
tyty = [1,2,3]
titi = [1,2,3]

var = []
var.append(tutu)
var.append(titi)
var.append(tyty)
return render_template("exemple.html", var = var)
```

and in your template:

```
{% for v in var %}
  {{ v }}
{{ endfor }}
```